# ¿Por que se produce este error?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-3.7, error404

Soy un poco nueva aun en python, estoy practicando con numpy, hacer un pequeño programa, pero me tira un error, pienso que puede ser donde tengo mal instalado numpy, pero no lo se

Adjunto foto del error y el codigo

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,3,5,6],[5,8,3,2])
print(a)
```

[image: Error que aparece]

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `numpy.array` tienes que pasarle **un** objeto, no dos.

Tu intención es crear una matriz de 4x2, el objeto tiene que ser una lista con dos elementos (uno por fila) y cada elemento con cuatro valores (uno por columna), que se escribe así:

```
[[2,3,5,6],[5,8,3,2]]
```

**Demo**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2,3,5,6],[5,8,3,2]])
print(a)
```

produce:

```
[[2 3 5 6]
 [5 8 3 2]]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio!